# 301 редирект с старого раздела в новый

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

У меня был такой раздел

```
site.ru/razdel/stranica.html
```

Я добавил еще одну категорию и получилась такая структура

```
site.ru/new_razdel/razdel/stranica.html
```

Редирект делаю так

```
RewriteRule ^shop/razdel/.*$ http://site.ru/shop/new_razdel/razdel/ [L,R=301]
```

Но у меня в таком случае все страницы, находящиеся внутри раздела razdel, редиректят просто на новый раздел

```
http://site.ru/shop/new_razdel/razdel/
```

А нужно, чтобы страницы переходили на страницы, каталоги на каталоги.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^shop/razdel(/.*)?$ http://site.ru/shop/new_razdel/razdel$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Спасибо. То что нужно!